# "Neuralnet" Library in R - Confusion Matrix

Tags: r, deep-learning, neural-network

I get an error message "all arguments must have the same length" when I run this code.

Would it be possible for someone to show me how to overcome this error, given `test$y,' and 'pred_label' both have the same input length?

I am currently struggling to generate a confusion matrix (ironically) from this data, and all help would be appreciated.

```
library(neuralnet)
library(tidyverse)


#MOCK DATA

x1 = rep(1:3, times = 40)
x2 = rep(1:3, times = 40)
x3 = rep(1:3, times = 40)
x4 = rep(1:3, times = 40)
x5 = rep(1:3, times = 40)

y = rep(0:1, times = 60)
y <- as.factor(y)

dat <- data.frame(y, x1, x2, x3, x4, x5)

#SPLIT

set.seed(123)

indexes=createDataPartition(dat$y, p=.85, list = F)
train = dat[indexes, ]
test = dat[-indexes, ] 

xtest = test[, -1]
ytest = test[, 1]

#MODEL

NN1 <- neuralnet(y ~., train,
                 linear.output = FALSE,
                 stepmax=1e7)


#ACCURACY TEST

pred <- predict(NN1, test)
labels <- c("0", "1")
pred_label <- data.frame(max.col(pred)) %>%     
  mutate(pred=labels[max.col.pred.]) %>%
  select(2) %>%
  unlist()

table(test$y, prediction_label)
```

I am currently following this tutorial. https://www.datacamp.com/tutorial/neural-network-models-r

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code

```
library(neuralnet)
library(tidyverse)
library(caret)

#MOCK DATA
x1 = rep(1:3, times = 40)
x2 = rep(1:3, times = 40)
x3 = rep(1:3, times = 40)
x4 = rep(1:3, times = 40)
x5 = rep(1:3, times = 40)

y = rep(0:1, times = 60)
y <- as.factor(y)

dat <- data.frame(y, x1, x2, x3, x4, x5)

#SPLIT
set.seed(123)
indexes=createDataPartition(dat$y, p=.85, list = F)
train = dat[indexes, ]
test = dat[-indexes, ] 

#MODEL
NN1 <- neuralnet(y ~., train,
                 linear.output = FALSE,
                 stepmax=1e7)


#ACCURACY TEST
pred <- predict(NN1, newdata = test)
colnames(pred) <- c("0", "1")
tab <- table(test$y, colnames(pred)[max.col(pred)])
confusionMatrix(tab)

#> Confusion Matrix and Statistics
#> 
#>    
#>     0 1
#>   0 3 6
#>   1 6 3
#>                                           
#>                Accuracy : 0.3333          
#>                  95% CI : (0.1334, 0.5901)
#>     No Information Rate : 0.5             
#>     P-Value [Acc > NIR] : 0.9519          
#>                                           
#>                   Kappa : -0.3333         
#>                                           
#>  Mcnemar's Test P-Value : 1.0000          
#>                                           
#>             Sensitivity : 0.3333          
#>             Specificity : 0.3333          
#>          Pos Pred Value : 0.3333          
#>          Neg Pred Value : 0.3333          
#>              Prevalence : 0.5000          
#>          Detection Rate : 0.1667          
#>    Detection Prevalence : 0.5000          
#>       Balanced Accuracy : 0.3333          
#>                                           
#>        'Positive' Class : 0
```

For ROC calculation, you can use the following code

```
library(MLeval)

pred <- predict(NN1, newdata = test)
colnames(pred) <- c("No", "Yes")

roc <- data.frame(pred, y = test$y, Group = "ANN") %>% 
  mutate(y = if_else(y == 0, "No", "Yes"))
  
ROC <- evalm(roc)
```

Comment: Thank you @ UseR10085. Really appreciate your help, +1. Would you by any chance know how to test the AUC for the NN1 model presented above?

Comment: I have updated my answer to include the AUC calculation.